# How to properly compare string values received from datagram packets?

Tags: java, string, datagram

I'm making a simple client server program. When the client sends the string "start", I want the server to start executing some code. Right now, I have the client sending a datagram packet with the message "start", the server gets the byte buffer from the packet, turns it into a string, and then compares that string value with the string literal "start". Obviously I'm doing something wrong because my code never enters the for loop of `if(sentence.equals(start){ System.out.println("ok");}`

My code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{


    byte[] receiveData;
    byte[] sendData;
    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(2014);


    while(true){

        receiveData = new byte[15];
        DatagramPacket frame = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(frame);
        InetAddress IPaddress = frame.getAddress();
        System.out.println("INET " + IPaddress);


        byte[] data;

        int port = frame.getPort();
        System.out.println("port " + port);

        String sentence = new String(frame.getData());
        String start =  new String("start");


        System.out.println("RECEIVED FROM CLIENT: " + sentence);


        if(sentence.equals(start)){
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So `sentence` obviously isn't `"start"`.  When you print it out, what do you see?

Comment: Are you sure it's even receiving anything? `DatagramSocket.receive` will block forever until it receives something.

Comment: Yeah it is start....that's what prints out when I print it out. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @DonRhummy yes it is most definitely receiving the datagram packet being sent to it by the client. It even prints out the word 'start', so I don't get why it won't execute the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Make the following change.

```
    String sentence = new String(frame.getData(), 0, frame.getLength());
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Why do I have to initialize the string with those two extra parameters though? I don't get why it won't work the other way.

Comment: @LePerMu It doesn't work the other way because your buffer is longer than the length of the word "start" (which is all the data sent)

Comment: @DonRhummy But I thought .getData() automatically 'cuts off' the bytes that weren't used?

Comment: @LePerMu "Returns the data buffer. The data received or the data to be sent starts from the offset in the buffer, and runs for length long." The `length` is the buffer's length, not the length of the data received.